# Problem to return component from StackNavigator in react-native. Get a blank screen but cosole.log is OK

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

What I want to do is wrapp on the very top of my app a switch navigator named MainNavigator which redirect to a LoadingScreen who determine if user is Logged or no and navigate to AuthNavigator or AppNavigator.
AuthNavigator himself is a stackNavigator who display screens 'LoginScreen' or 'SignUpScreen'. 
AppNavigator is a DrawerNavigator with multiple screens (Profile, Home...).

The problem I encouter is that the return method seems to work, because I can see the logs in my console from the 'LoginScreen' component but on the screen, the only return is a white screen.. When I call directly my 'LoginScreen' component from the LoadingScreen component by using :

```
_bootstrapAsync = async () => {
const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

// This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
// screen will be unmounted and thrown away. switched to develop the app
this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'LoginScreen');

};
```

I had the LoginScreen component rendered on my device.

I know the problem come from my AuthNavigator and AppNavigator because I can return screens components from AuthLoading or MainNavigator
Here some code :

```
 * Main Navigator: entry point of the app
 * Redirect to AuthLoadingScreen by default,
 * if user is signed (AsyncStorage) or successly signIn
 * redirect to AppNavigator else if user isn't SignIn
 * go to AuthNavigator

import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react- 
navigation';

import AuthNavigator from './auth/AuthNavigator'
import AppNavigator from './app/AppNavigator'
import AuthLoadingScreen from '../screens/auth/AuthLoadingScreen'


export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
  // You could add another route here for authentication.
  // Read more at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html
  AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
  App: AppNavigator,
  Auth: AuthNavigator,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }

  ));
```

AuthLoading :

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

export default class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away. switched to develop the app
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {

    return (
      <View>
      <Text>Loading</Text>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

AuthNavigator:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from '../../screens/auth/LoginScreen';
import SignUpScreen from '../../screens/auth/SignUpScreen';

export default createStackNavigator({
    Login : {
        screen : LoginScreen
    },
    SignUp: {
        screen : SignUpScreen
    }
    }, 
    {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    })
```

LoginScreen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
    render() {
      console.log('LOGIN SCREEN')
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Login</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
}


  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    text : {
      fontSize: 20,
    }
  });
```

I can't find the error, but I know it comes from the AuthNavigator and AppNavigator. I can see the 'LOGIN SCREEN' or 'APP SCREEN' if I set the AuthLoading route to render App in my console but nothing on the screen, when I init a new route LoginScreen in my MainNavigator and navigate to that route from the AuthLoading it works, I have a beautiful text displayed on my screen.

I Know it's probably an insignifiant error but I spend hours to fix this by myself and can't find, so if someone can help me it would be nice!

Thanks by advance!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved... Because at the top of my app in App.js I wrapped my MainNavigator like that

```
<View>
<StatusBar hidden={true} /> 
<MainNavigator />
</View>
```

So I remove the view and statusbar... and it works. 4 days to figure it out... I love it! :')

Comment: i am facing still same issue on android device it is working on iOS devices well but not in android devices. screens becomes white when come back on the same screen from the another screen of drawer.